# Why is CRTP pattern used in Visitor in boost graph library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I want to learn how [Visitor concepts](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/graph/doc/visitor_concepts.html) works in boost graph library by writing a vistor of my own. The [source code](https://github.com/boostorg/graph/blob/develop/include/boost/graph/visitors.hpp#L195) of `base visitor` and `time_stamper EventVisitor` is,

```
  // needed for MSVC workaround
  template <class Visitor>
  struct base_visitor {
    typedef on_no_event event_filter;
    template <class T, class Graph>
    void operator()(T, Graph&) { }
};

  template <class TimeMap, class TimeT, class Tag>
  struct time_stamper
    : public base_visitor<time_stamper<TimeMap, TimeT, Tag> >
  {
    typedef Tag event_filter;
    time_stamper(TimeMap pa, TimeT& t) : m_time_pa(pa), m_time(t) { }
    template <class Vertex, class Graph>
    void operator()(Vertex u, const Graph&) {
      put(m_time_pa, u, ++m_time);
    }
    TimeMap m_time_pa;
    TimeT& m_time;
};
```

`time_stamper` is a class derived from base class `base_visitor`. The type of template argument of base class is derived class itself. I believe this pattern is called curiously recurring template pattern(CRTP).

My question is, why is CRTP used here? The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) page shows CRTP is often used to acheive static polymorphism, but it doesn't look like so in this case.

I implement a simple visitor myself.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace boost;
using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS>;

struct tree_edge_event_visitor
  : public base_visitor<tree_edge_event_visitor> // works without this line
{
    using event_filter = on_tree_edge;
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void operator()(Edge u, Graph const& g)
    {   
        std::cout << source(u, g) << "->" << target(u, g) << '\n';
    }   
};

int main()
{
    Graph g;
    std::random_device rd; 
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());
    generate_random_graph(g, 10, 16, engine);
    write_graphviz(std::cout, g); 

    std::vector<default_color_type> color(num_vertices(g));
    std::cout << "Writing out tree edges: ";
    depth_first_visit(g, 0, dfs_visitor(tree_edge_event_visitor()),
        make_iterator_property_map(color.begin(), get(vertex_index, g)));

    return 0;
}
```

It does work, and it continues to work *without* deriving from `base_visitor`(see comment in code). So why is CRTP used here? The comment `need for MSVC workround` seems to suggest this pattern is for MSVC only.

**Update**: The change is made [here](https://github.com/boostorg/graph/commit/56f4ebbfa6671da594d2513d2ec1eb805e8de387#diff-a366b4b714dd736ecf975fb07d501814) in year 2000. The older version of `time_stamper` does not use CRTP. I think the rationale for the CRTP usage is specific to a very old version of MSVC. I cannot test it in modern MSVC unfortunately, as I don't have Windows machine around.

```
  template <class TimePA, class TimeT, class Tag>
  struct time_stamper {
    typedef Tag event_filter;
    time_stamper(TimePA pa, TimeT& t) : m_time_pa(pa), m_time(t) { }
    template <class Vertex, class Graph>
    void operator()(Vertex u, const Graph& g) {
      put(m_time_pa, u, ++m_time);
    }
    TimePA m_time_pa;
    TimeT& m_time;
};
```

Comment: "but it doesn't look like so in this case." your example just demonstrates that it can be done without (assuming your example is ok), but by no means this is a contradiction to CRTP being used in boost to enable static polymorphism. In general it is hard to know why code was designed like it is unless you ask the one who wrote it...

Comment: FWIW, this was apparently added in 2000 when the current version of MSVC was 6.0.

Comment: @hvd Thanks for reminding me that I can find when the code was added through `git log`. I will update my post when I find it.

Comment: @JohnKoch I used `git blame` -- or actually, the web interface to that, to find https://github.com/boostorg/graph/commit/56f4ebbfa6671da594d2513d2ec1eb805e8de387.